# RxJava2 and Room with loop

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, rx-java2

I have a program where data is stored in a local database using Room, and I receive data through RxJava2. In Provider, the database created a method that takes one parameter - an identifier, by which it sends a request and receives certain data that corresponds to the identifier. But I want to pass as a parameter not one identifier, but an array of identifiers and get an array as well, but I don't know how. I don’t want to implement it through for, because I think there is a better solution, but I couldn’t find it. My code is shown below.

```
...
userDatabase.userDao().getById(id)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(SchedulerProvider.ui())
            .map {
                InfoStruct(
                    it.Name.toString(),
                    it.Id.toString()
                )
            }
            .subscribe(
                {println("${it.userName} || ${it.userId}")},
                {println("Error")}
            )
...
```

I pass one value to the getById method parameter - an identifier, and send a request like this: select * where id =: id. I want to pass an array of identifiers as a parameter to get data for several users at once, but I don't want to change the structure of the request. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dao, e.g. getByManyIds(), that uses a WHERE clause that returns a list based upon a provided list.

The SELECT clause could be along the lines of

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE id IN (:idlist)"
List<your_type> getByManyIds(appropriate_type idlist);
```

appropriate_type should be an array of the id's int[], long[], String[] etc as is suitable (Room will generate the appropriate comma separated list).

Comment: Will it be rude if I put subscribe in for, where the loop goes through each element of the array?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Dao method looks like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = :id"
Single<User> getById(String id);
```

You need to do is change it to this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id IN (:ids)"
Single<List<User>> getByIds(List<String> ids);
```

And then use it like that:

```
userDatabase.userDao().getByIds(listOfIds)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(SchedulerProvider.ui())
        .map { users ->
            users.map {
                InfoStruct(
                    it.Name.toString(),
                    it.Id.toString()
                )
            }
        }
        ....
```